# Input text click is not showing up in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a contact form in a lightbox. When i open it in IE the textfield is not in active mode. it will only active after double clicking on it.
Check my page, There is a click to connect menu in the right side of the page and there is a dropdown menu "Schedule a demo" and it have a form, when i open that from IE i couldn't type character in that until i double click on it.

here my code

```
<div class="click_to_cnct_form_set">
    <label>
      Name *
    </label><input type="hidden" value="Schedule a demo" id="hid" name="hid">
    <input type="text" maxlength="100" class="form-control" data-placement="bottom" tabindex="1" id="name" name="name" title="">
  </div>

  <div class="click_to_cnct_form_set">
    <label>
      Email ID *
    </label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="100" class="form-control" data-placement="bottom" tabindex="2" id="email1" name="email1" title="">
  </div>
```

and here my 
[Live Demo](http://www.flutura.com/flutura_performance/)

Comment: This could have something to do with your javascript but unfortunately the Javascript on that site is minified.. Could you post any relevant javascript? Thanks.

Comment: Check now brother. I have linked the actual js

Comment: Your live demo is not showing the page...

Comment: Chrome does not show any lightbox .... .. error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function index_inline_min.js:1`

Comment: which page is not showing up?

Comment: Whatever change you made seems to have resolved that ... it's showing **Schedule a demo**. IE has these errors: 
`File: flutura_performance, Line: 791, Column: 118
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'live'
File: index_inline_min.js, Line: 1, Column: 3605
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
File: custom_jquery_min.js, Line: 1, Column: 6723`
The first occurs when the page loads while the second occurs when **Schedule a demo** is clicked.

Comment: Evidently, you're using `.live()` in `1.11.1` which was removed in `1.9` .... `e("a[data-reveal-id]").live("click",function(a){a.preventDefault();......`. Please take care of that

Comment: i have replaced 'live' with 'on' still it is not working.